# Where to put conversion functions?

Tags: c#, coding-style

As C# lacks support for freestanding functions, I find it hard to find a place to put conversion functions. For example, I'd like to convert an enum to a number. In C++, I would make the following freestanding function for this:

```
UINT32 ConvertToUint32(const MyEnum e);
```

How can I elegantly do this in C#? Should I make a dummy static class for holding the function, and if so, how can I find a meaningful name for it? Or should I make a partial class Convert?

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance.

**Update**: In retrospect, my example was not very well chosen, as there exists a default conversion between enum and int. This would be a better example:

```
Person ConvertToPerson(const SpecialPersonsEnum e);
```

Comment: MyEnum e = (MyEnum)3;
or
MyInt i = (Int)e; are both acceptable ways to convert between int and enum in C#.  That being said, I always put my conversion functions in a utility class.

Comment: +1 `partial class Convert` is good idea.

Comment: If you want a conversion from an enum to a class Person then **write a conversion operator**. Why mess around with a method when you can just write an operator that does what you want?

Comment: @Eric: Can this be done in the general case where the Person class and the SpecialPersonsEnum are inside third-party libraries?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. The code for the conversion operator must go inside the declaration of one of the things being converted; in this case, it would have to be the Person declaration, since you can't put code inside enums. We are considering a feature "extension conversions" which would allow you to do what you describe; if you have a really awesome scenario for that I'd love to hear about it.

Comment: @Eric: When I asked this question, I really didn't expect extension methods to work on enumerations also. Since they do, I think the extension method solution is good enough. The only gain I can think of is consistency, which would be nice but not necessary.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I'd go with:

```
namespace ExtensionMethods
{
    public static class MyExtensions
    {
        public static int ConvertToInt(this MyEnum e)
        {
            var m;

            // ... Implementation

            return m;
        }
    }   
}
```

Then you'd simply use `MyEnum.ConvertToInt();` The same can be done for multiple conversions all from within the same class. Extension methods are in a nutshell, damn sexy.

---

Also, [Eric's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/88656/eric-lippert) comment about Type Converters got me googling. Pretty awesome, however I'm not sure how to use them with an `Enum`, but for other conversions, they're clean as a whistle to implement. Have a look here:

- http://www.pluralsight.com/community/blogs/fritz/archive/2005/12/09/17343.aspx

Answer (score 9):

The above example looks like a candidate for an Extension Method.
If that's not possible, I define them as static methods in a static class ; I'd normally put them in a static class called XXXHelper

Comment: In this specific case a cast would be fine, in the general case I agree with Gishu and try to use extension methods before spawning a "helper" class.  Keep the functionality as close to where it belongs as possible (whilst maintaining SRP of course).

Comment: You're right! I didn't expect extension methods to work on enumerations, but apparently they do.

Answer (score 1):

I would recomend that you create and assembly that would contain all your *helper methods/constants and enums* that will be used in other projects.

This will allow you to easily include this assembly with other assemblies that need it and avoid circular references.

Answer (score 1):

Can't you just use a cast for this? `(UInt32)e`. Or else call `Convert.ToUInt32(e)`

Comment: Yes, but I'm talking about the general case. My example was merely to make the situation clear.

Answer (score 1):

The idea of creating a static "dummy class" seems to be what Microsoft suggests:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383974.aspx

I think in your particular example doing a partial class Convert makes the most sense.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the similar problem once and I did this

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        string s = "123";
        int n = Convert.StringToInt(s);
    }
}

class Convert
{

    public static int StringToInt(string s)
    {
        // implementation
    }
    public static string IntToString(int n)
    {
        // implementation
    }
}
```

Comment: for that ...why dint you use the .Net System.Convert Class?